# PID file ERROR with MYSQL on Yosemite

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite

For the life of me, I cannot start mysql on my OSX machine running 10.10.

I tried completely uninstalling MYSQL by following these instructions; https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x

Then, I reinstalled using this awesome script;
https://github.com/MacMiniVault/Mac-Scripts/blob/master/mmvMySQL/mmvmysql-README.md

Then that didn't work, then I uninstalled again and tried installing with brew.

```
brew mysql install
```

That appeared to install with some success, but one caveat:

```
A "/etc/my.cnf" from another install may interfere with a Homebrew-built
server starting up correctly.
```

I tried to find that file and I couldn't find it on my machine.  So I tried to startup mysql;

```
Batman:~ Matt$ mysql -uroot
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
Batman:~ Matt$ mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Batman.local.pid).
```

Comment: Have you tried to kill all mysqld process followed by mysql restart

Comment: it's not being used, and i can't even log in?

Comment: check if any mysql instance is running `ps -ef | grep mysql`        If yes kill those process `kill -9 PID `   Then try to start the mysql  `mysql.server start`

Comment: $ ps -ef | grep mysql
    0    38     1   0 Thu11AM ??         0:00.03 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql
   74   222    38   0 Thu11AM ??         0:11.19 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/localhost.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/localhost.pid
  502  4432  1311   0  3:19PM ttys002    0:00.01 grep mysql

Comment: it looks like those are processes that are somehow running? how do i kill those?

Comment: First try to stop the `mysql.server stop`. if it doesn't try to shutdown `mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown`. If it is a clean shutdown then fine . else kill forcefully `killall mysqld`.

Comment: i get the same errors... `Batman:~ Matt$ mysql.server stop
 ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!`

Comment: $ mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
Enter password: 
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!